# Jquery to Check Radio Button before Submitting Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a form using JQuery to check if a radio button is selected or not before submitting the form and I'm running into some issues. Below is the code that I'm using. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML (just my radio button):

```html
<!--Radio Button-->
    <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" id="myradio"> This is my radio button              
    </label>
    </div>

<!--Submit Button-->
<input value="sub" src="http://google.com"  type="image" id="button" name="sub"/>
```

Jquery:

I have 3 rules to account for:

Rule 1) If "myradio" radio button is Checked and "name" == 'John' then Submit the form.

Rule 2) Else If "myradio" radio button **is not** Checked and "name" == 'John'then just reload current page

Rule 3) Else Submit the form.

My first Rule (Rule 1) seems toe be working, but Rule 2 just submits the form and I can't figure out why it's not working.

```js
  $('#button').click(function () {
   var name = $.getQuery('name');

   if ($('#myradio').prop("checked") == true && name == 'John')       {
    $('#button').submit(); 
   } 
   else if ($('#myradio').prop("checked") == false && name == 'John') {
    location.reload(true);
   } 
   else {
    $('button').submit();
   }
  });
```

Comment: *"image: A graphical submit button. You must use the src attribute to define the source of the image and the alt attribute to define alternative text. You can use the height and width attributes to define the size of the image in pixels."* (Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input )  From the sounds of the MDN doc on `<input type="image">`, that is already a submit button.  So the form will submit without you doing the `.submit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// implement the "getQuery" for Stack Overflow
jQuery.getQuery = function () {
  return prompt("What should the name returned be?");
};

// dummy out the reload for Stack Overflow
var reload = function () {
  console.log('The window would have reloaded');
}

// catch the form submit
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('The form would have submitted');
});

$('#button').on('click', function (e) {
  var name = $.getQuery('name');
  
  // #button is already going to submit the form
  // so we do not have to do any .submit() on it.
  // We do, however, want to cancel the form submit
  // if the condition is we just want to reload the page
  if ($('#myradio').prop('checked') == false && name == 'John') {
    // stop the form submit, as we are going to reload the page
    e.preventDefault();
    // reload the page
    reload(true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" id="myradio"> This is my radio button</label>
  </div>

  <input value="sub" src="http://google.com"  type="image" id="button" name="sub">
</form>
```

Comment: @Talpar, this got me what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```js
$('#button').click(function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();

    if ($('#myradio').prop("checked") === true && name === 'John')       {
        $('#button').submit(); 
    } 
    else if ($('#myradio').prop("checked") === false && name === 'John') {
        location.reload(true);
    } 
    else {
        $('button').submit();
    }
});
```

```css
$body-color: blue;

body {
  color: $body-color;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>webpack starterkit</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>webpack starter</h1>
  <p>✨ A lightweight foundation for your next webpack based frontend project.</p>
  <div><input type="text" id="name"/> </div>
  <!--Radio Button-->
  <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" id="myradio"> This is my radio button              
   </label>
   </div>

<!--Submit Button-->
<input value="sub" src="http://google.com"  type="image" id="button" name="sub"/>
<script
  src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```